# Splitting strings into characters using DTL in Sesam

Tags: sesam

I wish to split a string into individual characters, but struggle to get the DTL correct.

I have:

```
"foo":"bar"
```

I wish to get

```
"foo":["b","a","r"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using "range" and "substring". Performance might not be great.

```
{
  "_id": "split-word",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "baz",
      "foo": "bar"
    }]
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["add", "foo",
          ["map",
            ["substring",
              "_.", ["plus", "_.", 1], "_S.foo"],
            ["range", 0,
              ["length", "_S.foo"]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Gives the following result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "baz",
    "foo": [
      "b",
      "a",
      "r"
    ]
  }
]
```