# Sesam DTL - check if string consist of letters

Tags: sesam

Is it possible to check for letters in a string? 
lets say I have this entity here:

```
[
    {
        _id: "1",
        "foo": "AD3495H2D23G"
    }
]
```

is there a way to figure out if foo consists of any letters or specific letters. lets say D and H. If they exist, filter out the entity.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using this [string to characters trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47634910/splitting-strings-into-characters-using-dtl-in-sesam).

```
{
  "_id": "letter-filtering",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "1",
      "foo": "AZ3495DX223G"
    }]
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
          ["filter",
            ["not",
              ["intersects",
                ["list", "D", "H"],
                ["map",
                  ["substring", "_.",
                    ["plus", "_.", 1], "_S.foo"],
                  ["range", 0,
                    ["length", "_S.foo"]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This will filter out the entity as long as `D` or `H` is in the foo prop.